# Auth0 create user issue

Tags: node.js, auth0

I'm trying to create a user which already exits in my Auth0.

for that, i'm using `mngClient.users.create`

The issue i'm encountering is that somtimes i get an error which looks like `APIError: {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"The user already exists.","errorCode":"auth0_idp_error"}`

And sometimes i get error which looks like `Bad Request: The user already exists.`

What is the reason for that?